# Migrating Glide 3.8 to 4.5, applyOptions not executed anymore?

Tags: android, android-glide

I just migrated from Glide 3.8 to Glide 4.5

When I use `GlideModule`

```
class ImageGlideModule : GlideModule {
    override fun registerComponents(context: Context, glide: Glide, registry: Registry) {

    }

    override fun applyOptions(context: Context, builder: GlideBuilder) {
        val detector = MainApplication.component.getPerformacneDetect()
        if (detector.isHighPerformingDevice) {
            builder.setDecodeFormat(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888)
        } else {
            builder.setDecodeFormat(DecodeFormat.PREFER_RGB_565)
        }
    }
}
```

I have in my Manifest

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.elyeproj.melbournemalaysianfood.ImageGlideModule"
        android:value="AppGlideModule" />
```

The `applyOptions` got called without issue.

However now I change to `AppGlideModule` (the version 4.5 approach) as below, using `@GlideModule` annotation.

```
@GlideModule
class ImageGlideModule : AppGlideModule() {

    override fun registerComponents(context: Context, glide: Glide, registry: Registry) {
        super.registerComponents(context, glide, registry)
    }

    override fun applyOptions(context: Context, builder: GlideBuilder) {
        val detector = MainApplication.component.getPerformacneDetect()
        if (detector.isHighPerformingDevice) {
            builder.setDecodeFormat(DecodeFormat.PREFER_ARGB_8888)
        } else {
            builder.setDecodeFormat(DecodeFormat.PREFER_RGB_565)
        }
    }
}
```

My `applyOption` didn't get called at all. I tried with and without the meta-data in Manifest, same thing happens. Did I miss anything? How could I get my `AppGlideModule`'s `applyOptions` get called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the reason it is not working. I need to add the `annotationProcessor` for glide, given I'm using `@GlideModule`. So in Kotlin, that's `kapt`

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
kapt 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
```

And also not forgetting to add

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

At the top of the gradle file